# Developing with Django+Celery without running `celeryd`?

Tags: python, django, celery

In development, it's a bit of a hassle to run the `celeryd` as well as the Django development server. Is it possible to, for example, ask `celery` to run tasks synchronously during development? Or something similar?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes you can do this by setting `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` in your settings.
(Constant was previously called `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER`)
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-execution-settings

Comment: This method is painfully slow sometimes. Any known issues?

Comment: Most likely it's slow because it's running the tasks synchronously (as desired) and they are slow.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Fixed the link: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-execution-settings

Answer (score 7):

There's also a custom Django test runner in django-celery that helps with CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER.
Read more about using Celery with Django on [the docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django).

Comment: link is broken: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-always-eager

Comment: Link is broken again.

Answer (score 5):

In version `4.0` of Celery `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` setting was replaced by `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER` in Django `settings.py` or `task_always_eager` natively in `celery conf`.

Since the numerous changes in the celery configuration from version 3.x to 4.x are spread over many lines, I suggest to use the built-in settings migration tool.

`celery upgrade settings --django`

source:

> Luckily you don’t have to manually change the files, as the celery
>   upgrade settings --django program should do the right thing.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#step-4-upgrade-to-celery-4-0

Answer (score 0):

After 5+ years of writing Celery tasks I have noticed a pattern I have developed that can help with testing and ease of development - I realised it is much better if my Celery tasks are thin wrappers around the regular Python functions that I typically put in `myproject.impl` package. Celery tasks may contain some strictly Celery related logic, like using distributed locking for an example, explicit retry logic, etc.