# Celery scheduled task eta(apply_async(eta=xxx:23) option is not working

Tags: python, django, celery

When I try to schedule the celery task using eta option, is not processing as expected date time.

**Code Snippet:**

```
 process_time_utc = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(x.utctimetuple()))
 process_request.apply_async(eta=process_time_utc,kwargs={'description':xxxx})
```

settings.py code snippet

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = Flase
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
CARROT_BACKEND = 'django'
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user2:xxx@localhost:xx56//'
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ADMINS = ()

# ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),

CELERY_IMPORT = 'xxx.app.tasks'
MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': '/test_data/test.db',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
}}



TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Here is the celery output log,

```
[2014-07-07 20:04:08,407: INFO/MainProcess] 
Got task from broker: xx.xxxx.app.tasks.process_request
[08029a2a-fdf0-4b50-b9a9-bdcf05ba71b5] eta:[2014-07-07 20:11:29+00:00]

[2014-07-07 20:04:48,785: INFO/MainProcess] 
Got task from broker: xx.xxxx.app.tasks.process_request
[624c5592-8ed6-4f2c-93df-d48af584a074] eta:[2014-07-07 20:06:29+00:00]
```

**Note:**
I have followed this tutorial http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html

Comment: can you show me some of your code?

Comment: Which version of Celery are you running?

Comment: Hi Banana, I am using celery==3.1.12 version.

Comment: Hi Rafael,I have added my code snippet.Is it problem with time format?

Comment: @Selva Maybe you should try using an external library as pytz to get the correct time (http://stackoverfldoingow.com/a/24616628/2801037)

Comment: Hi, Seems now working fine but it accept only UTC time

Comment: For Future Use,Its working as expected when you give Correct UTC Time Format to eta value.

Answer (score 2):

Eta parameter always has a past datetime. Try to add some delay (seconds, minutes, what you need) or use the countdown parameter

Comment: eta: Have you tried with local datetime(not utc)?. Otherwise, Has you used the countdown parameter?

Comment: Yes friend.I tried with both utc and local time seems its not working.

Comment: Have you defined the CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER parameter in your settings?

Comment: Yes.I have tried with CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True seems not working. Regarding countdown parameter only allow time format.But my requirement needs to date time format delay.

Comment: If you define CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER, it must be False, otherwise it will be execute at the moment  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498966/django-celery-how-to-start-a-task-with-a-delay-of-n-seconds-countdown-flag

Comment: Hi Friend, when i try to run the request with yesterday date on eta option.Its processing the request.If i specify the delay time, it will not processing as expected

Comment: Hi, Seems now working fine but it accept only UTC time.Thanks for your support!

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Would you please show me your client code to send task?  @Selva

Comment: @cherish Will you solved this issue in your application? or do you required any help? ETA will accept only the  proper UTC time format.

Comment: @Selva yes, I soved this issue. You should use utc time other than local time ```time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 
              time.gmtime(time.mktime(time.strptime("2008-09-17 14:04:00", 
                                                    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))))```   see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python